# Google maps (API v3) with kml layer. how to hide kml URL?

Tags: google-maps, kml, wikimapia

I would like to di splay a Google Map with a kml inside through API v3. the proble is that every one can see the url of the kml and easily download it. Is there a trick to 'hide' the .KML URL?

wikimapia.org seems to do something similar displaing kml polygons but if you check with Firebug through the script tag you won't see the kml URL.

thanks everyone for help. 
A. from Italy.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate it at run time, so that the server sends the page the URL. However, it is still discoverable at some point. Security through obscurity just doesn't really work. The KMLLayer Layer requires your KML to be on a public server. You could instead parse the KML and render it that way, say using [egeoxml](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/egeoxml.htm). However that delivers much less performance.